# Magento site can be redirected to pages like google.com when adding it to the end of my URL

Tags: magento-2.1

I have website that can access eg. google.com, youtube.com and other sites by adding it after a backslash like so http://www.exact-construct.ch/http://www.google.com

But if it is https://www.exact-construct.ch/http://www.google.com it wont be redirected. What could be the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The URL is using you are adding google.com at the end of the base URL of the site. This URL is not available that-why it returns `404`.

If you try the same thing with any site it would be the same result.

Please tell me your requirements more, if this won't help you.

I will be happy to help ypu.

### Happy Coding!